# Enumeration of graphs with a given and bounded degree sequence

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, degree-sequence

What is the best known asymptotic formula for the number of graphs with a given degree sequence $(d_1, ... ,d_n)$, when the degrees are bounded by a constant and the number of vertices $n$ goes to infinity?

There are several papers of McKay et al. that provide bounds when the degrees are all $O(n^{\frac{1}{2}})$, but I am interested in bounded degrees, and I was hoping for more exact bounds for this special case. There are works on this as well, but they all seem to be pretty old, so I was wondering what the current state of the art is.

Comment: You can take the asymptotic formula for given degrees and sum it over all degrees within the bound.  It isn't altogether trivial, but I'm pretty sure Nick Wormald did it somewhere.  Sorry but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay doubtlessly knows more, but his paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.4218v1.pdf with Catherine Greenhill seems very a propos...

Comment: Or maybe my memory was mistaken, since I was thinking of http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316502000171 which has minimum degree not maximum degree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my comment I was misreading the question, sorry.  The situation for the real question is as follows. For very low degrees (say, at most 3) it isn't hard to get the exact number as a single or double summation.  For the more general case of bounded maximum degree, the best asymptotic formula is [my result with Wormald](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/nickcount.pdf) (Combinatorica, 11 (1991) 369-382), which in this case has an error term $O(1/n)$ where $n$ is the number of vertices of non-zero degree. It would be possible (though somewhat tedious) to find an explicit bound on the error term, but as far as I know nobody has done it.  It would also be possible (in this special case of bounded degree) to obtain the precise term of order $1/n$ and have an error term of size $O(1/n^2)$.  But, again, I think nobody has done it.