# Asymptotic estimation of numbers of unlabeled graphs whose degrees of vertices are bounded

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, riemannian-geometry

It is [known](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~tvis/Coursework/Graphs.pdf)([Enumeration of graphs with a given and bounded degree sequence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136375/enumeration-of-graphs-with-a-given-and-bounded-degree-sequence)) that there is no a closed form formula for number of (labeled) graphs with bound on degree of vertices. Thus what I want to know is whether there is an asymptotic estimation of number of such **unlabeled graphs** like those here [Strauss&Ikeda].

For symmetric (unlabeled) graphs, we can reduce the problem of counting how many graphs(with certain properties) to certain form of group representation problem that can be solved using [Polya's enumeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem). However, if we put a bound on the degrees of vertices(or edges) of a graph $G$, usually we lose symmetries.

For graphs with such a bound on degrees of vertices, it is of importance in classification of Riemannian manifolds as well as physics since they can usually be realized as 1-skeleton of a class of manifolds (See: [Can you determine whether a graph is the 1-skeleton of a polytope?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9255/can-you-determine-whether-a-graph-is-the-1-skeleton-of-a-polytope)) and it is known to connect with the $L(\epsilon)$ covering of small geodesic balls.

> Thus each equivalence class of manifolds is chracterized by the
>   abstract unlabelled graph $\Gamma_{\epsilon}$ defined by the
>   1-skeleton of the $L(\epsilon)$-covering. The order of any such
>   graph(i.e. the number of vertices) is provided by the filling function
>   $N_{(\epsilon)}$...[Mark J. Gotay et.al]pp.175-177(around it...do not have that book at hand)

Such results may also refine some statistical inference like the one here [Gao&Massam].

So I want to know the state-of-art in the direction of finding an asymptotic estimation/bound on the number of graphs with a bound on degrees of vertices. This post is different from [Enumeration of graphs with a given and bounded degree sequence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136375/enumeration-of-graphs-with-a-given-and-bounded-degree-sequence) and the [paper](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/nickcount.pdf) given there since we are dealing with **unlabeled** graphs in this post.

**Reference**

[Strauss&Ikeda]Strauss, David, and Michael Ikeda. "Pseudolikelihood estimation for social networks." Journal of the American Statistical Association 85.409 (1990): 204-212.
http://hbanaszak.mjr.uw.edu.pl/TempTxt/PDF/Strauss_Ikeda_1990_PseudilikelihoodEstimationForSocialNetwor.pdf

[Mark J. Gotay et.al]Mathematical Aspects of Classical Field Theory,AMS 2010 http://www.ams.org/books/conm/132/conm132-endmatter.pdf

[Gao&Massam]Gao, Xin, and Hélène Massam. "Estimation of Symmetry-Constrained Gaussian Graphical Models: Application to Clustered Dense Networks." Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics 24.4 (2015): 909-929.